# Translate one line of C# to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm always using C# to VB.NET Converter and it works perfect.
But now I've got a little problem:

```
private static int[] ChunkInput(string input)
        {
            var numberOfBlocks = ((input.Length + 8) >> 6) + 1;
            var blocks = new int[numberOfBlocks * 16];
            for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                blocks[i >> 2] |= input[i] << ((i % 4) * 8);
            }
            blocks[input.Length >> 2] |= 0x80 << ((input.Length % 4) * 8);
            blocks[numberOfBlocks * 16 - 2] = input.Length * 8;
            return blocks;
        }
```

Everything was translated correctly by my converter until one little line:

```
blocks[i >> 2] |= input[i] << ((i % 4) * 8);
-> was made to :
blocks(i >> 2) = blocks(i >> 2) Or input(i) << ((i Mod 4) * 8)`
```

The Failure Message is:
The <<-Operator is not defined for types "char" and "integer".

I have no idea what those byte-shift opperators actually do, that's why I cant solve that problem at all :( Could anybody help me out?

Comment: Replace `input(i)` with `Asc(input(i))`

Comment: What is the data type you get from the converter for numberOfBlocks?

Comment: are you using 64bit of vb.net?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error says, don't use `<<` for `char`.

try following code:
`blocks(i >> 2) = blocks(i >> 2) Or Ascw(input(i)) << ((i Mod 4) * 8)`